# Automatic navigation without using Google voice

Tags: android, google-api

Currently working on an app . It uses Google map API to locate nearby doctors. We have a feature that shows nearby hospitals in our current location. Although on clicking the same a map opens in new tab but markers are shown, we want directly to navigate to  the nearby hospital in the area and not be shown in marker format. What should we do?

Answer (score 0):

First, need to get latitude-longitude of the particular nearby hospital using your current location then after you need to set marker with custom pin or icon. Then after you need to move mapcamera using hospital lat long.

**Get current location:**
 https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#java

**Move To Direct on Location:**

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

**Custom Marker:**
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker